# jquery redirect behaving differently than clicking link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with jquery 1.9.

I have a small system in place to detect if a user has made changes on the screen before navigating away.

I have the following code in a script tag in my view (the setChangesMade function just sets a global variable that signifies changes were made on my screen):

```
 $(function ()
 {
     $(window).bind('beforeunload', function ()
     {
         //Prompt the user to save changes if we have identified any as being unsaved.
         setChangesMade(true);

         if (changesMade)
         {
             return 'You have unsaved changes. Do you want to leave the page without saving changes?';
         }
     });

 });
```

If I make changes on my screen and then click on a link this code works fine.  After the message, the user can click OK to navigate away and lose changes or cancel to stay put.  Both scenarios work perfect when navigating away using a link on the page.

But if I navigate away using the following:

```
var url = ScriptResolveUrl("~/MyController/MyActionMethod");
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

The message box still pops up as expected.  If the user clicks OK, he gets navigated away successfully as expected.  But if the user clicks cancel at the message box and decides to stay on the page, an unknown jquery error is thrown.  There is no info about the error either.  It just says jquery error on line 3.

Why would this work perfectly fine when clicking a link, but not when using the jquery redirect?